# coffeescript and jquery producing complete url for background image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, jasmine

I am trying to set the background image of a div using coffeescript and jquery. I get the image url from a data source in the DOM in the form `/images/album_image1.jpg`.

However, when I use:

```
$('.selector').css({'backgroundImage', "url(#{image_url}"})
```

CoffeeScript/jQuery produces a URL with the host:

```
url(http://host.com/images/album_image1.jpg)
```

Furthermore, Firefox will enclose the URL in quotes while Chrome won't quote the URL.

See here: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/adicol/6/edit)

I wanted to get the result `url(/images/album_image1.jpg)`, that is without the host part and without the quotes. I am hoping to get the latter result in order to pass my testing using Jasmine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you're javascipt you'd want to output the text with `'+something+'` so:

```
 var image_url = $('img').data('img');
 image_url = str.split(".com"); //split returns an array of everything after the regex: .com
 image_url = image_url[1];
 $('.selector').css('backgroundImage', "url("+image_url+")");
```

**Edit**

```
 So if you want to remove the leading url from the returned string you would use split:

 var str = 'http://jsbin.com/images/image_album1.jpg'
 str = 
 image_url = str.split(".com"); //split returns an array of everything after the regex: .com
 str[1]; ///images/image_album1.jpg
```

Hope this helps? But i have updated the above as well, so its helpful in your case.

Comment: Not sure this is answer is helpful, not that your fiddle is up there. Didn't work before. To be the output text in your fiddle looks fine.

Comment: `"url("+image_url+")"` produces the same output as `"url(#{image_url})"` in coffeescript (using interpolation).

Comment: ye, as i saw in your fiddle you're getting the correct output.

Comment: Is it not possible to get the URL without the host part, i.e. `url(/images/album_image.jpg)` which, afaik, is valid css?

Comment: sure it is. just slit the string up once you have it. I'll update and you can play with it after.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Indeed that would get the intended result. Was just wondering if there was some other way without through that extra step.

Comment: arghhh... nope don't believe there is.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem does not lie in the string that is being passed to the $().css() function. As in the above scenario, the strings are all in the form `/images/image_1.jpg` without the host path. So, there is nothing to split and splice. The crux seem to lie in the $().css function of jquery, where it generates an absolute path for the background image's url. I guess, the only way to go is to bend the tests. :(